# Remove existing annotation and add new annotation into the mapview

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I am loading a mapview with a single annotation. Just like the "map app" in iphone. I have a search bar, which shows the address of the pin location, shown in map. Now I decide to change the location address. I type a new address location in the search bar. Then my mapview has to remove the existing annotation and add the new annotation. Right now, I am adding the new annotation, but I am unable to remove the existing annotation. How can I remove that  existing annotation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, get the list of annotations on the map view, and then remove the annotations that are not the current user location (i.e. in the `MKUserLocation` class).

```
NSArray *annotations = [mapView annotations];
for (id annotation in annotations) {
    if (annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]) {
        continue;
    }
    [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Then you can add your new annotation as normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom annotations another way could be this:

```
for (int i =0; i < [mapView.annotations count]; i++) { 
    if ([[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]]) {                      
         [mapView removeAnnotation:[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]]; 
       } 
    }
```

In this way remove just the annotations you have added.

Comment: Fast enumeration is the preferred method of iterating a collection these days.

Comment: @Abizern Sure, i know and i use fast enumeration too..but a clarification, if the annotations mapview array reflects another array, with a custom for loop i can access/compare elements by the index. If i've understand correctly with FE we've just an id reference, so could i do this with fast enumeration?